# html code accepts 2 lists of email add, L1 & L 2.clicks submit btn, display a third list L3, that has email add present in Lt 2 but not in L1

Tags: javascript, html, css

html code that accepts two lists of email addresses. List 1 & List 2. When user clicks submit button, display a third list List 3, that has email addresses present in List 2 but not in List 1.

Comment: html code that accepts two lists of email addresses. List 1 & List 2. When user clicks submit button, display a third list List 3, that has email addresses present in List 2 but not in List 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
// Array 1:
var myArray = ['abc@gmail.com', 'pqr@gmail.com', 'def@yahoo.comc'];

// Array 2:
var secondArray = ['abc@gmail.com', 'pqr@gmail.com', 'def@yahoo.comc', 'kri@gmail.com'];

//Final Array with EmailId which is not in Array1
var diff = $(secondArray).not(myArray).get();
console.log(diff);
```